# MKS Gen V1.4 won't work when connect to computer via USB

Tags: usb

My board programmed OK using Arduino software and spoke back to me on the USB port.  I then installed it in the system.
The display worked fine selecting menu items when powered up.
However, when I plugged the USB connector in, it all went dead. 
When I disconnected everything and connected up to the Arduino software, it spoke to me again.  Now if I connect it up to the power supply, with only other connection the display (Smart Controller), it seems OK, but display goes blank when I connect the USB.
Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to 3dPrinting.SE!